# Where does the get_input_port method reside in drake?

Tags: c++, drake

I'm trying to find the template function that this call is referring to

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/pendulum/pendulum_geometry.cc#L102

```
  const auto& input = get_input_port(0).Eval<PendulumState<double>>(context);
```

I've been trying to find the import  that contains this call but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's at
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/systems/framework/system.h#L927

(Because PendulumGeometry derives from LeafSystem.)

Comment: Add'l links: [permalink](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/7cf93ce48c760b953425a31b840fa9dcd0eaad47/systems/framework/system.h#L927), [C++ API](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#a39b7b9f7723ad69fca8766e6590ef681)